# Count the elements in a list that matches certain conditions

Tags: python

I have a list, say:

```
   list = ['KAYE', 'DAVID', 'MUSIC', '88', 'ART', '45', 'FRENCH', '36']
```

I want to count how many marks that are less than 50 in the list, so I wrote:

```
count = 0
if  list[3] < '50' or list[5] < '50' or list[7] < '50':
    count = count + 1
```

But count is always 1, it doesn't accumulate when there are more than one marks that are less than 50.

How can I fix this? Thanks a lot for helping

Comment: What those indexes (5, 7, 9) represent?

Comment: Don't use strings to compare numbers and use sum to get the count

Comment: ... and don't use  built-ins as variable's name

Comment: The index (5,7,9) was from the original array, they should be(3,5,7) for this one. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running one test, that looks at multiple possible conditions and executes one piece of code if ANY of them is true.

I think you want to count how many of the marks are <50, and report the total.

Let's do a simple version, and grow from there:

```
student = ['KAYE', 'DAVID', 'MUSIC', '88', 'ART', '45', 'FRENCH', '36']
ALARM = 50

num_alarms = 0

if int(student[3]) < ALARM:
    num_alarms += 1
    print("Alarm! The " + student[2] + " grade is too low!")

if int(student[5]) < ALARM:
    num_alarms += 1
    print("Alarm! The " + student[4] + " grade is too low!")

if int(student[7]) < ALARM:
    num_alarms += 1
    print("Alarm! The " + student[6] + " grade is too low!")

if num_alarms != 0:
    print("There were " + str(num_alarms) + " grades too low.")
```

That does what I think you're trying to do. But we can clean it up a bit:

```
student = ['KAYE', 'DAVID', 'MUSIC', '88', 'ART', '45', 'FRENCH', '36']
ALARM = 50

num_alarms = 0

# count from 3 .. by 2
for score in range(3,len(student), 2):
    if int(student[score]) < ALARM:
        print("Alarm! The " + student[score-1] + " grade is too low!")
        num_alarms += 1

if num_alarms != 0:
    print("There were " + str(num_alarms) + " grades too low.")
```

Finally, we can go "full Python" and add list comprehensions:

```
alarms = [ student[class_] for class_ in range(2, len(student), 2) if int(student[class_ + 1]) < ALARM ]

for class_ in alarms:
    print("Alarm! The " + class_ + " grade is too low!")

num_alarms = len(alarms)

if num_alarms != 0:
    print("There were " + str(num_alarms) + " grades too low.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only running your code once, so of course the maximum count can be is `1`.

---

If you want to test each element in a `list` and see how many are numbers that are `< 50`, you can do this:

```
count = 0
list = ['strings','morestrings','12','4334','anotherstring']
for val in list:
    try:
        val = int(val)
        if val < 50:
            count += 1
    except ValueError:
        continue

print(count)
```

Comment: I've fixed the code that I'm posting, sorry for the confusions

Answer (score 0):

You are using an `if` statement to check for multiple things.  If one of them succeeds, it runs the next line (only once) that increments `count`.  Try something more like:

```
my_list = ['KAYE', 'DAVID', 'MUSIC', '88', 'ART', '45', 'FRENCH', '36']
count = 0
for i in [3,5,7]:
    if int(my_list[i]) < 50:
        count += 1
```

for which `count` is 2 (45 and 36 are <50).  This iterates through the indexes you specify (`[3,5,7]`).  The `for` loop runs the check on each one and increments `count` if it evaluates to True.

Also, I have renamed your `list` to `my_list` (as suggested by @user3100115) because `list` is a built-in symbol for lists.

I find it strange that you already know the indexes to check.  This is fine if you already know it.  But what if you don't?  You could check through the whole `my_list` for any number less than 50 with:

```
my_list = ['KAYE', 'DAVID', 'MUSIC', '88', 'ART', '45', 'FRENCH', '36']
count = 0
for i in my_list:
    try:
        if int(i) < 50:
            count += 1
    except:
        pass
```

The `try` and `except` stuff is because the interpretation of `i` as an `int` might throw an error if it's not actually a number.  The `except: pass` ignores it if this conversion fails.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
count = len([x for x in (list[3], list[5], list[7]) if (int(x) < 50)])
```

and -- as shown here -- you do need to convert to an int before comparing, or else, for example, "100" will come out as less than "50".

Answer (score 0):

Just another short way...

```
>>> marks = ['KAYE', 'DAVID', 'MUSIC', '88', 'ART', '45', 'FRENCH', '36']

>>> sum(int(x) < 50 for x in marks[3::2])
2
```

This would also work if David had more or fewer than three marks.